# Is there any way to know if a user gave consent on behalf of an organization

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-oauth

Organization administrators have an option to "Consent on behalf of your organization".

This feature enables them to give consent for all users within the organization. As a result, users of the organization can sign up without needing to provide individual consent. In Microsoft documentation, this is referred to as [admin consent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/enterprise-apps/user-admin-consent-overview#admin-consent).

Is it possible to check if organization-wide consent was given using any of the following sources:

1. [OAuth response](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#successful-response-2) or [JWT Token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/id-token-claims-reference#payload-claims)
2. [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/azure-ad-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0)

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can list [oAuth2PermissionGrant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/oauth2permissiongrant?view=graph-rest-1.0) entities, which represent delegated permissions granted to enable a client application to access an API on behalf of the user.

`oAuth2PermissionGrant` has the property `consentType` which indicates if authorization is granted for the client application to impersonate all users (tenant-wide) or only a specific user.

Possible values of the `consentType` property are:

- `AllPrincipals` - tenant-wide consent
- `Principal` - consent for a specific user

You can filter permission grants by `consentType`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/oauth2PermissionGrants?$filter=consentType eq 'AllPrincipals'
```

The response looks like this

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "clientId": "f5913df3-bd00-4259-aa45-a17a008b033c",
            "consentType": "AllPrincipals",
            "id": "xxx",
            "principalId": null,
            "resourceId": "0741d31a-647d-4821-b3d6-99aeea5e0123",
            "scope": "User.Read User.ReadBasic.All"
        },
        {
            "clientId": "f5913df3-bd00-4259-aa45-a17a008b033c",
            "consentType": "AllPrincipals",
            "id": "xxx",
            "principalId": null,
            "resourceId": "3c4020a9-f9ce-4790-ba8f-4f85b0ff62d5",
            "scope": "Files.Read.All"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
```

It can return more records for a specific `clientId` if some sets of permissions have been granted during time.

To find details about the client app, use `clientId` in the request

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/servicePrincipals/{clientId}
```